# Can dust affect USB Ports?

Tags: power-supply, usb

I recently deployed a custom RFID-based accessed control system.

Before deployment, we (me and my team) did rigorous testing of the system (Linux machine) as well as individual modules (python client, node backend), we found multiple issues during testing which resolved.

RFID Readers are connected to the system. Randomly these scanners didn't get power and hence card isn't read by the system.

The only factor that is different in a production environment when compared to the testing environment is dust. Does someone have any experience with something similar?

Edit:
Dust is my assumption. Please bear with this is my first posting a problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once the port has a plug in it there isn't much way for dust to get in.  How are you certain the scanners aren't getting power?  Does the power just drop out or does it stay off?

Comment: Do the RFID readers stay rigidly fixed in one place or are they frequently moved around ?

Comment: Abdul Rehman - Hi, You said: "*Randomly these scanners didn't get power and hence card isn't read by the system.*" Unless you have test equipment attached to every scanner/reader, it's not clear how you would know that power has been lost and so your statement about random power loss sounds like an assumption. There are other environmental reasons why RFID readers won't read, nothing to do with power. Be careful to tell us only facts that you can back-up with evidence :-)  So please [edit] the question to add the evidence of actual *power loss* and describe your troubleshooting so far. Thanks.

Comment: is the USB port subjected to vibration?

Comment: @K H There is an LED on RFID readers when readers arent working that led is off.

Comment: @AJN yes readers are rigidly fixed.

Comment: Hello @sam, it is my first time posting a problem and English isn't my first language sorry for the miscommunication from my side.
I don't have the proper equipment but there is an LED light on the reader it is off when readers arent reading.

Comment: @jsotola no readers are fixed.

Comment: @AbdulRehman - Thanks for the update. From experience, your question is unlikely to do well here (remote troubleshooting is difficult!), as it started with a [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) - dust is not *your* problem (irrespective of the answer to your question "Can dust affect USB Ports?"). There are many possible troubleshooting approaches which *could* be applied, but there is little information here to guide that choice. I will leave you with one recommendation: Find out, *in as much detail as possible*, the "meaning" of the LED which goes off, on affected readers.

Comment: i did not ask if readers were fixed ... i asked if the USB port is subjected to vibration ... that means, if you touch the USB connector, do you feel vibration from what the device is attached to? ... I have seen connector contacts getting separated by dust ... the dust worked itself between contact surfaces because the device was vibrating as a result of slightly unbalanced fans

Comment: @samg Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @jsotola I will ask someone at the deployment location to let me know if there is a vibration. Due to the covid19 situation, I am debugging the problem remotely.